# Quick U-turn on foot?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I was playing the first Trevor rampage mini game when I'm sure it popped up saying press 'X' and something to perform a quick u-turn.

Any ideas what it is or did I just misread it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Xbox 360, click and hold down the Right Analog Stick, then pull the Left Trigger.

On PS3, click and hold down the Right Analog Stick, then pull <kbd>L2</kbd>(or <kbd>L1</kbd> if you are using alternative layout).

Comment: Just a note, this only applies when you have a gun drawn. He also may have seen the Combat roll with is LT + X on the 360, which also only applies with a gun drawn.